# External VPN users cant access mapped network drives with Name have to use IP address

Tags: vpn, watchguard, shared-storage

It's not a massive problem but some users complain they can't access our storage drive when working externally across the VPN.

For instance, internally they can type `\\storageserver\adminfolders` and it works with no problem.

But externally it won't resolve the name and they have to use the IP address instead.

```
\\192.168.168.168\adminfolders
```

Using the IP address it works.

I'm not sure if it's a DNS issue (it seems that way due to the fact that the IP works and not that name) or something else.

Any suggestions?  The only things we have are McAfee Security on the laptop and a Watchguard firewall that runs the VPN clients over PPTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to check:

-Does using the FQDN for the share work (ie, \storageserver.domain\adminfolders)?

-Try toggling the "Use Default Gateway on remote network" setting in the TCP/IP v4 properties for the PPTP connection.  Be aware, though, this will route all remote traffic through the tunnel, and could be a bandwidth sink.

Comment: i used the FQDN and that worked. any more suggestions?

Comment: Well, at this point it's a preference issue.  You can do a few things:

-Manually add a domain suffix so FQDN isn't needed.
-Make a manual entry in the each local hosts file for the server(s) needed.
-Make the default gateway change suggested above for the PPTP connection object
-Map the drive using the FQDN

Personally I wouldn't mess with the first two options, and I'd shy away from the 3rd as well.  I've had many users "forget" they were still signed on to VPN and fire up Netflix (or worse. ;) ).  If it's a company owned asset, usually I just make a persistent mapping using the FQDN.